# Script not resuming execution after providing the required authorization

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with Google App Script required in the background. The script is using certain scopes that cause it to require authorization.

Upon sharing the sheet with someone, on his first run, he has to authorize it. So far so good. However, after providing the authorization, the script does not continue its execution.

In short, desired behavior in this scenario:
Click a button
The authorization window appears
Authorization is completed
A popup saying "Button click" appears

Actual behavior:
Click a button
The authorization window appears
Authorization is completed
No popup is displayed. I have to click the button again to get the popup with the message.

My question is whether my desired behavior is even possible - can the script continue execution after the user provides authorization?

Comment: Add your star here, please: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154161164

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible.

I suggest you to include in the workflow for your users an "install" step to throw the script authorization then after that do the others steps.

References

- [Authorization for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization)

Comment: Hi, I have pretty much come to the same conclusion, but have been unable to verify without doubt that it is not possible. I do not seem to be able to detect the text in the link you provided that suggest so. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Hi ! **Does your script have an trigger?** Is it an addon? I believe [in this part](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization#permissions_and_types_of_scripts) although not explicitely it explains that the script would be run from the new user. As it is the first time that user access it, the script on his end hasn't been run yet (it is like a brand new copy of the script in his account).